# Copying production database setup to development database

Tags: sql, database, local

I am using Oracle 9i, Please suggest how can I select data from one remote database and insert the data in the local database?

Also suggest how the data can be copied from a remote to remote database.

Comment: @OMG, I have updated details, please check

Comment: And why on earth would you only want some records from prod on your dev database?

Comment: This is for replication of the issues occured on production on development database without affecting other rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a database link.

Please refer to this link: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/ds_concepts.htm#12354

excerpts:

example:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK sales.us.americas.acme_auto.com CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'sales_us';
```

query:

```
For example, using a database link to database sales.division3.acme.com, a user or application can reference remote data as follows:

SELECT * FROM scott.emp@sales.division3.acme.com;  # emp table in scott's schema
SELECT loc FROM scott.dept@sales.division3.acme.com;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the vagueness of the question.  Make a backup of production and restore it in development.

Comment: I do not need to copy all the entire data, or a tables, Instead I need to copy rows from one table from remote database to local database

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking Microsoft SQL then you can create a Linked Server.  Here is an article about doing this in SQL 2008, but you can do it in earlier versions as well.  Then you can select from it using a four part name LinkedServer.database.schema.table

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Define a link from the development server to the prooduction server.   You can then use a select based insert to copy data into the development server.

Use the SAMPLE clause on the select to retrieve a percentage of the data.  For child tables use a WHERE exists clause to copy child rows for which the parent was sampled.